# How can I apply css styling to the current day in the calendar widget

Tags: widgets, calendar

How can I apply css styling to the current day in the calendar widget? It seems there is no css class for the current day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my default calendar widget I get:

```
<td id="today">30</td>
```

so you could use `#today`.

It uses the `get_calendar()` function where we have the following:

```
if ( $day == gmdate( 'j', $ts ) &&
    $thismonth == gmdate( 'm', $ts ) &&
    $thisyear == gmdate( 'Y', $ts ) ) {
    $calendar_output .= '<td id="today">';
 } else {
    $calendar_output .= '<td>';
 }
```